# Alias template of a class given as a template parameter c++

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

How to refer to an alias template of a class `A` given as a template parameter to a class `C` that inherits from a template base class `B`?

```
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    // the alias template I want to refer to:
    template<class T>
    using Container = std::vector<T>;
};

// the base class
template<template<class> class _Container>
struct B 
{
    _Container<int> m_container;
};

template<class _A>
struct C : public B<   typename _A::Container  >
{//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 

};

int main()
{
    C<A> foo;
}
```

I tried several solution by adding the `template` keyword at every possible place in the statement (like `template<class T> typename _A::Container<T>`, `typename _A::template Container`...) but `g++` gives either *"template argument 1 is invalid"* or *"type/value mismatch"*!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
template <class A>
struct C : public B<   A::template Container  >
{
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QknwnJUDGJTGdgQy)

BTW: Don't use `_A` as the name of template parameter, [identifiers beginning with an underscore followed immediately by an uppercase letter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/3309790) is reserved in C++.